Can there be a fundamental contrastive explanation to reality?
By contrastive, I mean, why is reality this way rather than another way?
No matter what sort of “fundamental” explanation grounds all of reality, or is the ultimate cause of all reality, can one not always ask the further question “but why this way rather than another way?”

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There is a great article on SEP about facts (brute, grounded, and otherwise) - some of that is relevant to this question (also see SEP article on PSR)

You raise a key point in the problem with always expecting an explanation for what appears to be a contingent fact. The possibility that ontic randomness may exist in our world (i.e., the outcome is not merely the result of chaos or some other unknown deterministic mechanism), means there are contingent facts.
If there are contingent facts, then not all facts are necessary facts. If not all facts are necessary facts, then the Principle of Sufficient Reason is not a universal rule:
If E(x) means "x can be explained" then

Universal PSR: ∀x: x → E(x)

But when a uranium 235 atom undergoes fission, that is a fact with no explanation that makes it necessary.
At best, the PSR is a great guiding principle but we should apply it knowing that truly contingent facts may be lurking out there. We can have a provisional "explanation" using criteria of theory selection (e.g. parsimony, coherence, transparency, etc) but it may just be us telling ourselves a nice "just so" story.

To the more core issue you bring up, a chain of explanations must end in a brute fact or go on forever. I haven't seen a "self-explanatory fact" except perhaps "I exist" or the immediate contents of our consciousness, if only because we consist in exactly these contents.
The allergic reaction to an infinite chain of explanations (called "Infinitism") is unwarranted, just like the concern over Achilles ever making progress in Zeno's Paradox.
It may be a ding on our ego, but it may not be possible for any finite being to grasp the global explanation of something. However, we are very capable of developing local explanations of something.
Its just another example of what I like to call the "Copernican Programme" - understand the world from the position that nothing is privileged or singled out.
Of course, with that in mind I'm a big fan of Modal Realism as an elegant provisional theory that can ground what we see. It only requires assent to:

True nothingness is incoherent
Ultimate reality exhausts all possibility

From that, we get that all possible worlds exist, and hence "locally" contingent facts turn out to be globally necessary.
The fact that it posits an uncountably large number of worlds is more of a limitation of the human imagination (and again our ego in needing to feel our particular world is special or the only one); it posits this to avoid those "contingent facts" that scream for explanation.
